# Structs data scrambled upon retrieval from NSValue

Tags: objective-c, struct, objective-c++

I'm putting in the values to a struct here :

```
[self createEntityWithX:20 andY:20 withType:0 withWidth:20 andLength:20 atSpeed:5];
...
...
-(void)createEntityWithX:(int)newEntityX andY:(int)newEntityY withType:(int)newEntityType withWidth:(int)newEntityWidth andLength:(int)newEntityLength atSpeed:(int)newEntitySpeed
{
  Entity tmpEntity;
  tmpEntity.entityX = newEntityX;
  tmpEntity.entityY = newEntityY;
  tmpEntity.entityLength = newEntityLength;
  tmpEntity.entityWidth = newEntityWidth;
  tmpEntity.entityType = newEntityType;
  tmpEntity.entitySpeed = newEntitySpeed;

  NSValue *tmp = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&tmpEntity objCType:@encode(struct Entity)];

  [entityArray addObject:tmp];
}


-(Entity)retreiveEntityFromValue:(NSValue *)value
{
  Entity entity1;
  [value getValue:&entity1];
  return entity1;
}
```

And the data is being scrambled when i get it back? I created the entity with : X:20 Y:20 Width:20 and getting back x : 1712736 Y : 0 Width : 0?
X is completely random, but the rest remain 0

Where have i gone wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your `value` pointer in the `retreiveEntityFromValue:`(sic) method is non-`nil`? If it is `nil`, `entity1` will remain uninitialised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using integers try using floats (1) or you could pass the data as a point(2).

1)http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_2.0_Data_Types#float_Data_Type
2)http://mobiledevelopertips.com/c/cgrect-cgsize-and-cgpoint.html